# Looping multiple scanner inputs that work together until a specific input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am new to java, and I am doing this assignment for a romanCalculator.
I am currently done with the calculation part but i am having an issue with some of the rules requested.

I want 3 type of scanner inputs to work.

1. (possible Roman number) (operator)

   (operator) (possible Roman number)

   .

The first will take a roman numeral input and use any operator on another roman numeral input 
Roman numerals are [MMCDXLVI].

I was able to create the program which takes 2 roman numerals and u calculate them depending on the operator input, but I wasn't able to have the second rule work.

It means if there's a result from rule #1, and i type (operator) (possible Roman number), it will calculate the last Roman number( the result) with the new input.

For example:

> ```
>  X + I (input)
>
>  XI    (output)
>
>  * II  (input)
>
>  XXII  (output)
> ```

So how do i make that work, how to have 2 viable inputs only and the second input uses the result of the first input.

This is all what i could do with my knowledge:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";

    while(!(input = in.nextLine()).equals("."))
    {
        String[] userInput = input.split("\\s+");



        if(userInput.length == 3)


        {
            String firstRoman = userInput[0];
            String operator = userInput[1];
            String secondRoman = userInput[2];

            int romanConvertedNumber = (compute(romanToNumber(firstRoman), operator, romanToNumber(secondRoman)));



            if(firstRoman.matches("[MCDXLVImcdxlvi]+") && operator.matches("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/") && secondRoman.matches("[MCDXLVImcdxlvi]+"))
            {

                IntegerToRomanNumeral(romanConvertedNumber); //method to convert number to roman

            }


        }

        else{
            System.out.println("Error: Wrong input");
        }
    }

}
```

It works for the first case only like said and terminates when i write (.), I don't how to apply to the result i get to (operator) (possible roman Number) like in the example, I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: didn't get the question as well :)

Comment: Okay sorry, i'll try my best to reexplain it.

Comment: You need to store the previous result, as that's the only piece of missing information

Comment: Ye but how and even then how will i apply a new input ? both inputs need to be in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be more like this, i did a few changes..

1. check if valid input format (using matches) should be before the **compute** call
2. in case its not valid input, you should also print an error message (even if length of input is 3 strings)
3. add new variable **lastResult**
4. actually print the result :-)

hope its good enough

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
String lastResult = "";

while(!(input = in.nextLine()).equals("."))
{
    String[] userInput = input.split("\\s+");

    if(userInput.length == 3)
    {
        String firstRoman = userInput[0];
        String operator = userInput[1];
        String secondRoman = userInput[2];

        if(firstRoman.matches("[MCDXLVImcdxlvi]+") && operator.matches("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/") && secondRoman.matches("[MCDXLVImcdxlvi]+"))
        {
            int romanConvertedNumber = (compute(romanToNumber(firstRoman), operator, romanToNumber(secondRoman)));
            lastResult = IntegerToRomanNumeral(romanConvertedNumber); //method to convert number to roman
            System.out.println(lastResult);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error: Wrong input");
        }

    }
    /* check if */
    else if( ( userInput.length == 2 ) & ( ! lastResult.equals("") ) ){ 
        String firstRoman = lastResult;
        String operator = userInput[0];
        String secondRoman = userInput[1];

        if(firstRoman.matches("[MCDXLVImcdxlvi]+") && operator.matches("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/") && secondRoman.matches("[MCDXLVImcdxlvi]+"))
        {
            int romanConvertedNumber = (compute(romanToNumber(firstRoman), operator, romanToNumber(secondRoman)));
            lastResult = IntegerToRomanNumeral(romanConvertedNumber); //method to convert number to roman
            System.out.println(lastResult);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Error: Wrong input");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error: Wrong input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my issue! :)

Comment: I have a question thought, when I add the negative sign to the first letter in input, it will skip because its not in the matches part of [MCDXLVImcdxlvi], any idea what can i do to avoid this? because i want it to work with negative sign for the first letter. Ty

Comment: you will need to add the minus sign to the characters in the "**matches**"  function, you are welcome :-)